# Can I find all of a certain base model in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Given a class-like relationship:

```
class A(db.Model):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass
```

Can I get all of the base class? The query:

```
models.A.all().fetch(1)
```

returns an empty list.

Comment: I assume for the purposes of this question, you actually have some elements of type `B` in the datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastore doesn't natively support this sort of polymorphism - but you can use the [polymodel class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html) to do this. Just inherit from PolyModel instead of Model and things will behave more or less as you expect them to.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore does not record inheritance, per se: it stores the `B` entities as being of kind `B`.  You can get all (direct, proper) subclasses of `A` with `A.__subclasses__()` (if you want  indirect subclasses as well you'll need to do the same with each of these, and so forth, recursively, until you stop getting subclasses), and perform all the `.all` queries on them.